# Java: How do I pass parameters to a Webstart Applet?

Tags: java, applet, jnlp, java-web-start, http-authentication

**Scenario:** server provides same Webstart Applet to many different (but authenticated) clients. Each Applet has to "know" which client it is on. Therefor the server has to be able to pass some parameters to the client, which is then read by the Applet, running on that client.

1. Is it possible for a Webstart Applet to access the **cookies of the web browser** from which it was launched?
2. Is it possible for a Webstart Applet to access the **URL** by which it was identified?
3. Some other options?

**EDIT:** Perhaps Webstart Applet is a wrong term. I mean just a Webstart Client App.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [`applet-desc`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#applet_desc) element in [*JNLP File Syntax*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html) for details.

Addendum: See also [*Accessing Cookies*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/doingMoreWithRIA/accessingCookies.html).

Comment: Well, this would mean that I *had* to generate something special for every client.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the cookie part of the question; link above.

Comment: I decided to go with your previous solution to dynamically generate the jnlp file.

Comment: I think this is a static solution. Is there any dynamic way to do this? I mean the case of a web form where the client enter parameters before launching ? Server side could write a jnlp file for every user click, but it doesn't seem to be a good way to do it

Comment: @Andrew Thompson may have some insight on this. Rather than writing a `jnlp` file for every user, I'd think the server could construct it on the fly, perhaps via a servlet. Naturally, I'd welcome a better solution.

Comment: yes, I mean to construct it on the fly but it doesn't seem to be a concurrent server solution, wait for @AndrewThompson opinion, thanks

Answer (score 2):

More pertaining to your 2<sup>nd</sup> point.  URL query parameters can be parsed using JavaScript and added to the `applet` element.  Attributes in the `applet` element will add to, or overwrite, the values set in the JNLP file.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, but sadly I can't use JavaScript for some reasons.